# Saving an Entry in listview to a class after pressing save

Tags: xamarin.forms, data-binding

as you know you cant call your Listview Items in code behind if they are populated with MVVM. soo I have a label in my list view that populated with MVVM and in front of it there will be some Enterys. When the Entrys are complete I can save them in a  class right away BUT I want this to be saved when the User presses the save Butten.

I cant call my Entrys by there name in the code behind when the Butten is clicked. Can any one give me any suggestion.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding JJ}">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                             <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="name" Text="{Binding name}"/>
                             <Entry x:Name="entry1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="1"/>
                             <Entry x:Name="entry2" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
                        </Grid>
             
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
            
            <Button Text="save" Clicked="Button_Clicked"/>
```

Comment: Use data binding to bind your Entrys to a model.  When the user clicks Save then save the data that are stored in the models.

Answer (score 0):

you use data binding

create a model class for your data

```
public class MyData
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value1 { get; set; }
    public string Value2 { get; set; }
}
```

then in your page

```
List<MyData> data = new List<MyData>();
data.Add(new MyData { Name = "One" });
data.Add(new MyData { Name = "Two" });
data.Add(new MyData { Name = "Three" });

MyListView.ItemsSource = data;
```

then in your XAML bind your entries

```
<Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
<Entry Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Text="{Binding Value1}" />
<Entry Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Text="{Binding Value2}" />
```

finally, in your save method you can access the bound properties

```
foreach (var item in data)
{
   // use item.Value1, item.Value2
}
```

Comment: tanx alot @Jason. I will try your code as soon as I get over this Covid.

Comment: HI. Jason. as I said I bind my listview to another page . how can i bound my Entrys to code behind too?? @Jason

Comment: I cant put all of these in 1 model. is there a way to use 2 model in list view or use code behind of the page  too

Comment: I have to use a Event handler in Entry to reach code behind , but entry text changed and text complete will save junk text....

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about.  You are referring to code that is not included in this post.

Comment: LOL. Im referring to Code page behind My Xaml page!

Comment: I understand that.  But you are talking about problems in code that I cannot see, so there is no way for me to help you.

Comment: And your solution can only saves the last Entrys TEXT. if I have 3 names in my model , this code saves only the last entry that user typed.

Comment: my code does not save anything, it just illustrates how to access ALL of your data so you can do whatever you need to with it.